# Query is significantly slower when filtering after a join, why?

Tags: postgresql, performance

I have a query that is 10 to 15 times slower when you move a specific filter to after a join happens and I can't for the life of me figure out what is happening under the hood that would cause this.

The query is very complex but when simplified the problem area is essentially this:

I have a table of items, that joins to a linking table that links items together. You can think of this like a parent -> child relationship.

```
Items 
id | type | name | ect.

Links 
parent_item_id | child_item_id | type | date | ect.
```

The query itself starts with a list of parents items, joins onto the links, and then back to the child items. Like so:

```
select * from items parent
left join links l on l.parent_item_id = parent.id
left join items child on l.child_item_id = child.id
```

I need to filter this query down by a list of child ids. This list is extremely long (around 45k items). If I apply the filter like so:

```
where child.id in (list_of_child_ids)
```

The query runs in around 2 minutes. If I apply the filter to the links table itself it runs in 10 seconds.

```
where l.child_item_id in (list_of_child_ids)
```

This is part of a much larger query that gets turned into a subquery to do a bunch of aggregations on it, and then that is turned into another subquery to do even more aggregations on, but when I look at the query planner none of that aggregation stuff is slow, it's just the joins to get the child items.

Does anyone know what would cause that significant of a performance difference?

Comment: One thing if you are requiring something to be in one of the LEFT JOIN tables, that is basically making it an INNER JOIN (because you requires something in that table).  So you maybe want to look at making it an INNER JOIN.  If you have a TON of subqueries, depending on how complex and how much data, you could get better performance by inserting into temp table then join/work off that.

Comment: Check if you have appropriate indexes on the parent_item_id and child_item_id columns in the links table, as well as on the id column in the items table. PostgreSQL can then use these indexes to speed up join operations and filtering.  If applicable, consider breaking down the query into CTEs (Common Table Expressions) or subqueries that allow for filtering earlier in the process.

Comment: We need to see your table definition, [indexes](https://use-the-index-luke.com/), and the result of [`explain analyze`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/using-explain.html#USING-EXPLAIN-ANALYZE) on both queries.

Comment: And please use `explain(analyze, verbose, buffers, settings)` to get all the details about the plan and the execution of the plan.